# Is there way to upload Intel and M1 both build combined together on Appstore?

Tags: macos, app-store-connect, apple-m1, universal, apple-developer

I am on working electron and I have created M1 build but the case is here like our app is already  developed with native code and uploaded on Appstore. we have re-written whole app in electron to support cross-platform so I don't want to touch a intel based app. Only just want to upload M1 build separately so no users will affect with existing build and we don't want to replace older build now.

can anyone help me out from this.

Comment: You can release a new app with your new code but if you submit an update to the existing app then the update will be available to all users. Your new app will include both arm and intel code

Comment: @Paulw11 It means uploading a new app will provide a option for M1 and intel. if I will change in existing app then it will send update notification to all user for m1 only or intel too. Do you have any links that explain how to proceed m1 build on app store?

Comment: Yes, a new app (different bundle id) will be available for both m1 and intel macs. An update to the existing app (same bundle id) will be available for m1 and intel macs. All users will get an update notification. If you use Xcode 12 then your build automatically contains m1 and intel code.  Remember that m1 macs can just automatically translate intel code too.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah got it it means we don't need to upload two different M1 and intel build on app store? app store will translate automatically based on the system.Am I correct ?

Comment: No, Xcode builds both intel and m1 slices and embeds the in the single package that you deliver to the App Store, but you are right you don't need to upload two separate builds

Comment: @Paulw11 do you have idea using electron JS how can I upload this type of binary  on app store ?